# WordPress doesn't show all posts

Tags: wordpress

Is there a reason why WP only shows a list of 10 posts? I'm using this code `$latestPosts = new WP_Query('cat=5');` to get a list of all posts that I have. I thought this should work, compared to this code: `$latestPosts = new WP_Query('cat=5&posts_per_page=3');` with a limit of 3 posts.

I have 19 posts, but in the list I only get 10. Is there some kind of pagination by default that I have to handle in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `posts_per_page` value to `-1`